# Translating a list of numbers to a graphic format (#)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So i am trying to get it to look like this in python 3:

```
How many hours are in your sample? 7
Enter the count of cars for hour #1: 2
Enter the count of cars for hour #2: 5
Enter the count of cars for hour #3: 9
Enter the count of cars for hour #4: 11
Enter the count of cars for hour #5: 12
Enter the count of cars for hour #6: 6
Enter the count of cars for hour #7: 5
Hour #1: # #
Hour #2: # # # # #
Hour #3: # # # # # # # # #
Hour #4: # # # # # # # # # # #
Hour #5: # # # # # # # # # # # #
Hour #6: # # # # # #
Hour #7: # # # # #
Average: # # # # # # #
```

And I have written this so far:

```
def main():
    hourlist = number_cars()
    graphic = hourlist
    car_count_graphic_format(graphic)



def number_cars():
    hours = input("How many hours are in your sample? ")
    hours = int(hours)
    hourlist = []
    for i in range(hours):
        hourcount = input("Enter the count of cars for hour #" +str(i+1)+ ": ")
        hourcount = int(hourcount)
        hourlist.append(hourcount)
    hourlist.sort()
    return hourlist


def car_average(car_count):
    car_sum = 0
    for position in range(len(car_count)):
        car_sum = car_sum + car_count[position]
    average = car_sum / len(car_count)
    return average

def car_count_graphic_format(graphic):

    for x in range(graphic):
        graphic = "#" * graphic
        print("Hour #:" ,graphic,)





main()
```

But whenever I run it, it has an error and i honestly am stuck at this point as to what to do. If someone could help me with this, I would appreciate it so much! Thanks for anyone that will be able to help me with this!

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Please do not delete questions after you have received an answer.

Comment: Please do not delete questions after they have been resolved but [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) instead. Deleting your own questions only hurts yourself, and the questions weren’t even bad, so there is really no reason to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

```
def car_count_graphic_format(graphic):
    for x in range(graphic):
        graphic = "#" * graphic
        print("Hour #:" ,graphic,)
```

You should be careful here, you are reusing the name `graphic` far too often—for different confusing things.

The function takes a list of car counts for each hour, so let’s call that argument `car_counts`. We want to print a line for each entry, so we have to iterate over the elements in `car_counts`. Note that we cannot use `range(car_counts)` here since `car_counts` is a list but `range()` expects a number. Instead, we can just directly iterate over the list to get each element in it in each iteration. Since we also want to take note of the hour, we use `enumerate()` to also get the index of the element in the list. Since the hours start at 1, we tell `enumerate()` to start counting at 1:

```
for hour, count in enumerate(car_counts, start=1):
    graphic = '# ' * count
    print('Hour #{}: {}'.format(hour, graphic))
```

Finally, we also want to find out the average, so we count the total number of cars, and then later divide by the number of hours (the length of the list) to get the average car count:

```
def car_count_graphic_format(car_counts):
    total_cars = 0
    for hour, count in enumerate(car_counts, start=1):
        total_cars += count
        graphic = '# ' * count
        print('Hour #{}: {}'.format(hour, graphic))

    average = round(total_cars / len(car_counts))
    graphic = '# ' * average
    print('Average: {}'.format(graphic))
```

Finally note that you do *not* want to sort your `hourlist` in the `number_cars` function, or you will lose the information which car count belongs to which hour.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!